# Struggling with SQL line

Tags: mysql, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am struggling with the SQL-like line, and I just don't know how to fix it.

```
query = "SELECT P_askbid_midprice1, Label1 FROM 'DCIX_OB' WHERE time >= '2018-02-16T09:00:00Z' and time <= '2018-02-16T16:00:00' "
```

I got the following error with the previous line :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph_influxdb.py", line 53, in <module>
    read_data(length='5min')
  File "graph_influxdb.py", line 29, in read_data
    result = client.query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 394, in query
    expected_response_code=expected_response_code
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 271, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"error parsing query: found DCIX_OB, expected identifier at line 1, char 39"}
```

How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Single quote string values (for example, tag values) but do not single quote identifiers (database names, retention policy names, user names, measurement names, tag keys, and field keys).](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#when-should-i-single-quote-and-when-should-i-double-quote-in-queries)
>
> Double quote identifiers if they start with a digit, contain characters other than [A-z,0-9,_], or if they are an InfluxQL keyword. Double quotes are not required for identifiers if they don’t fall into one of those categories but we recommend double quoting them anyway.

I.e. use `FROM "DCIX_OB"` (`FROM DCIX_OB` is also legal but not recommended).

Comment: Today, the fact that identifiers without double quotes are legal (albeit not recommended) seems still a valid statement, as the online manual still says so. However, this line works `idbc.query("SELECT value FROM SCADA WHERE \"section\" = 'LILJEN' AND \"name\" = 'PM01PY'")` while this one doesn't `idbc.query("SELECT value FROM SCADA WHERE section = 'LILJEN' AND name = 'PM01PY'")`. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Alkhwarizmi Because `name` falls under "or if they are an InfluxQL keyword", so it _must_ be quoted. See https://github.com/influxdata/influxql/blob/master/README.md#keywords

Comment: Thank you @Alexey, I was not aware of that